# consolidated contents of all txt files into one- Python

Tags: python, glob

I'm trying to consolidate all the result.txt file contents inside result folder and generating "Result_STD.txt" file out of it. But before writing to a file
I want to add a str(GenerateFile) once but currently for every file append that string is getting added.
Can anyone please suggest me how to add that string only once in a file?

```
def createOutput(self,STD):
    directory = "/result"
    read_files = glob.glob(directory + "/" + "*_result.txt")
    with open(directory + "/" + "Result_" + STD + ".txt", "wb") as outfile:
        for f in read_files:
            with open(f, "rb") as infile:
                data = infile.read()
                new_data = '{"GenerateFile":'+ data +  '}'
                print(new_data)
=================================================================
                
Current Output:

GenerateFile:{
    "Message": "CREATED", 
    "Result": "DONE"
}
GenerateFile:{
    "Message": "CREATED", 
    "Result": "DONE"
}

==============================================================
                
expected output:

GenerateFile:{
    "Message": "CREATED", 
    "Result": "DONE"
},
{
    "Message": "CREATED", 
    "Result": "DONE"
}
```

Comment: If you want something to happen only once, should you put it inside the loop that iterates over the multiple input files, or outside? If you want to output the `GenerateFile` tag before the `{}` items produced by the loop, should you put the code that does that output before the loop, or after it?

Comment: Your output doesn't match the code. But still to do what you want print/ write 'GenerateFile:' right before `for f in read_files:` and then new data can simply be `data` with commas and stuff

Comment: @Devon Horizon, write 'GenerateFile' before loop it worked. Can you please tell me how to separate the contents of each file using a comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you need it to do?

If so, all I did was move the `new_data` string initial assignment of `GenerateFile:` out of the `for f in read_files:` loop and append to it inside the loop, then print the output at the end of the loop.

```py
def createOutput(self,STD):
    directory = "/result"
    read_files = glob.glob(directory + "/" + "*_result.txt")
    with open(directory + "/" + "Result_" + STD + ".txt", "wb") as outfile:
        new_data = "GenerateFile:"
        for f in read_files:
            with open(f, "rb") as infile:
                data = infile.read()
                new_data = new_data + " {" + data + "}, "
        print(new_data)
```

You might need to remove the last `,` before `print(new_data)` if it's a problem.

Comment: Hi @WSC, before starting the loop I have written new data into the file it worked. But how to separate each file with a comma?

Comment: In the above code I put `new_data = "{" + data + "},"` does this not do what you are expecting?

Comment: It add a comma to the last content also. example:GenerateFile:{
    "Message": "CREATED", 
    "Result": "DONE"
},
{
    "Message": "CREATED", 
    "Result": "DONE"
},

Comment: @WSC append to `new_data`. After that this should work

Comment: @DevonHorizon Good spot, fixed.

Comment: @vinuta Yes, that trailling comma is expected. I mentioned it in my answer. You should be able to work out how to remove a trailling comma. :)

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the tick to accept it.